# Pandas .groupby automatically selecing column

Tags: python, pandas

From the following dataset:
[image]

I'm trying to use .groupby to create a set where I get the average Status Count per User Location. I've already done this for Follower Count by using

```
groupLoc = df.groupby('User Location')
groupCount = groupLoc.mean()
groupCount
```

Which automatically selected User Location vs Follower Count. Now I'm trying to do the same for User Location vs Status Count, but it's automatically including Follower Count again.

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
print df.groupby('User Location', as_index=False)['Follower Count'].mean()
     User Location  Follower Count
0           Canada     1654.500000
1          Chicago     9021.000000
2        Indonesia     1352.666667
3           London      990.000000
4   Los Angeles CA       86.000000
5         New York      214.000000
6        Singapore      106.500000
7            Texas      181.000000
8               UK     2431.000000
9        indonesia      316.000000
10            null      295.750000

print df.groupby('User Location', as_index=False)['Status Count'].mean()
     User Location  Status Count
0           Canada  39299.000000
1          Chicago   6402.000000
2        Indonesia  12826.000000
3           London   4864.666667
4   Los Angeles CA   3230.000000
5         New York   2947.000000
6        Singapore   6785.500000
7            Texas    901.000000
8               UK  81440.000000
9        indonesia  17662.000000
10            null  29610.875000
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks

Comment: Super, I try improved solution by `as_index=False` for returning `DataFrame`.